# Regex with 2 different texts

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an editor and in editor i have to find matches and replace specific texts with predefined text or just find matches.

Suppose I have text like this

```
if (VALUE('Name') == 'Jhon Doe') {
  SET_VALUE('Jhon Abraham');
} else if (VALUE('Address') == '512 Lane') {
  SET_VALUE('Whitehouse lane')
}
```

I have these 2 regex but this fails

```
/VALUE\(('|").*('|")?\)/g
/SET_VALUE\(('|").*('|")?\)/g
```

Because of second regex the first also find SET_VALUE as VALUE. I am still learning regex and new to this one.

Between i am using Monaco editor where i have to use autocompletion

```
 provideCompletionItems: (model, position) => {
    const textUntilPosition = model.getValueInRange({
      startLineNumber: 1, startColumn: 1,
      endLineNumber: position.lineNumber, endColumn: position.column
    });

    const regexConstructCompletion = textUntilPosition.match(/VALUE\\(('|").*('|")?\\)/);
    const attributeSuggestions = regexConstrcutCompletion ? autoCompleteAttributes : [];

    return attributeSuggestions;
  }
```

also i am not allowed to used reverse regex

Comment: Use  a word boundary, `/\bVALUE\(['"].*?['"]\)/g`

Comment: what do you mean by "also i am not allowed to used reverse regex" ?